# Bootstrap icon content is not exactly in the middle

Tags: css

This is my website's settings button.

[image: Settings button]

It may be visible, but it is slightly tilted to the upper right.

It is not a failure of vertical center alignment. I want this **bootstrap icon gear-fill** to actually be **exactly in the middle** of the div.

Here is my html and css:

```html
<span class="float-end btn-setting" on:click={modalMypage.show} on:keydown={modalMypage.show}>
  <i class="bi bi-gear-fill"></i>
</span>
```

```css
.btn-setting {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color .2s ease;
}
.btn-setting > i:before {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #959FFF;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.btn-setting:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.btn-setting:hover > i::before {
  color: white;
}
```

As you can see in the css, I've currently tried using display: `flex`, `align-items-center`, `justify-content-center` to center align it.
It appears to be centered at first glance, but as mentioned before, it is slightly shifted to the top right.

Not only is it hard to see, but it's not that important. But now that I've been watching it for months, it's starting to get on my nerves.

Is there a good solution?

Comment: Can you try this: add "display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;" to ".btn-setting" and remove "position: absolute;inset: 0;display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center; from ".btn-setting > i:before". Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Div_P I tried several methods to solve this problem, and the method you suggested is actually the method I used just before. Unfortunately, this produces exactly the same results as the current method.

Comment: Did you remove the position property from this style - .btn-setting > i:before ?

Comment: Can you check this code: https://jsfiddle.net/divyap/ubtjcae7/

Comment: I applied the same as this: Even if you compare the style sheets line by line, they are the same. That's strange.

Comment: @Yeol can you please set up and link a fiddle with your code? It is actually not clear, which "div" you mean. Your code example does not contains a div.

Answer (score 0):

try to add class="align-middle" to the span tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).